# C# Connection String

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, web-config, connection-string

I am using the following connection string within the `<configuration>` node. But somehow, it seems that it is not saving. Every time I use

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myDB"].ConnectionString
```

it has a `null` value, and when I check the index `"0"` it points to `.\SQLEXPRESS`.

```
<connectionStrings>
   <clear/>
   <add name="myDB"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
        connectionString="Server=Server\Instance;Database=anydb;User Id=***; Password=***;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

The projects is an ASP.NET MVC 2 project.

I really need this to work, since I am learning the code-first Entity Framework. Is there any suggestions?

Comment: Which type of authentication you are using? sql server or windows? Database server is on separate server or not?

Comment: Are you sure you put <connectionStrings> section into proper config file? In case of ASP.NET MVC project it should be placed in web.config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things to trouble-shoot on this :

- Ensure that EF is configured to use your connection string. You can do this in you DbContext class by passing the connection string name into the base constructor :

  ```
      public class YourContext : DbContext
  {
       public YourContext()
         : base("myDB")
     {

     }
  }
  ```
- Ensure that the connection string is the correct web.config (ie in the main root not in Views)
- Check that the connection string is not being overridden in the web.debug.config (or web.release.config) if it is being